# OpenCart 1.5.x to 2.x

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I need to perform an upgrade on an existing OpenCart installation which is currently version 1.5.4. It has a lot of users (1500+) and products and I need to keep all the data. I stumbled across this "guide" http://learn.opencart2u.com/ which seemed legitimate, so I followed all the steps until I got to

> Go to your database and import the migration sript.

This was a problem because the page does not send the "migration script". I looked all over the web but I couldn't find the file in question.

I want to ask, if you have the file in a secret golden archive, in the depths of your hard drive, could you possibly help a fellow programmer in need.

Additionally, if nobody has the file in question, would it work out if I installed a fresh copy of OC 2.0 and manually truncated all tables that exist in the 1.5 version, then filled them with the data from the old installation. Then modules and extensions will need to be re-installed but that's of no matter to me.

I am asking this to find if anyone has come across the same problem and could save me a handful of hours, or worse, days.

Thanks in advance and any help will be of great appreciation.

Comment: Good luck, literally. There is no easy way to do it, not even with 2 clear installs of each version. This is why there is no fully working script for migrations, just some brave attempts to do so. I would suggest you do it by hand like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate your store manually, we don't need for any script. Here are few steps to update OC version

```
-> First of all backup your existing store.
-> Then upload all new files of new version on root of your website (if website are running on root).
-> then go to www.yourdomain.com/install
-> It will automatically update your version & you will never loose your existing data.
```

But before doing updation, you should have to cross check all extensions has version 2.X compatible version available in market that you are already installed otherwise you would have to make compatible manually.

After updation you would have to update all extensions with version 2.X that you're using.

Also you have to do all customization in new version if in case you did in your store before.

Comment: This is true for versions before 2.0, however updating from 1.5 to 2.0 does not work this way, if you install 2.0 files over a 1.5 OC you start getting mysql errors because of differences in the database.

Comment: did you run the OC default updation script ? I have done couple of store update for my clients with this process successfully. Can you share please share the error that you got after it ?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not able to because I had time restrictions and I did it manually, however I remember it was a database error caused by differences in table schema. I'll assume I did something wrong and trust you it works, so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This could help

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19572

Found the link on a discussion on the subject here, which you may find worth a read

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=138627

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the response. I literally turned the web inside out, I found every possible "migration", "upgrade" and "converter" tools and none of them work (free ones). The one you are referring stops working on the last page as many other, when you click submit or export just nothing happens.